# Publish expo to stores

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo

I'm using windows and i've `expo 3.28.5` installed and trying to publish my app to google play store.

I run `expo build:android` [OK]

So when run `expo upload:android` i receive:

> Local Android uploads are only supported on macOS.

I can't publish apps on windows SO.?

Answer (score 1):

In documentation it is clearly mentioned `expo upload:android` is available for macOS only https://docs.expo.io/distribution/uploading-apps/#21-if-you-choose-to-upload-your. But you can always upload `.aab` files generated manually. To do so, build the app using `expo ba -t app-bundle` and copy the generated `aab` file to play store.

Comment: Oh, thanks. And to upload to AppStore, only with macOS?

Comment: Yes, to upload to app store you must have a macOS device.